# My React-Helmet isn't working in my login component?

Tags: meta-tags, react-helmet

I don't understand what I am doing wrong with introducing React-Helmet to my website's components.

I already installed react-helmet using terminal command:  **npm install --save react-helmet**

There are NO "title" or "description" tags inside my index.html file.

**Here is the condensed Component Code inside a .js file:**

```
    ...
    import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';

    class LoginFullscreen extends Component {
                
    ...
                return (

                    <div className='login-fullscreen-background'>

                      <Helmet>
                          <title>Unlocked Academy: Login to the Platform</title>
                          <meta name="description" content="Welcome to Unlocked Academy!  Login here to access your account and prepare the flashcards you will engage with after each phone unlock and passing screen time!" />
                      </Helmet>

                      ...

                    </div>
                    
                 );
                 
                 ...

}
```

**Here is my index.html file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
       <head>
           <meta charset="utf-8" />
           <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/Favicon32x32.png" />
           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
           <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />

           <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    
       </head>

       <body style="background-color: #3A3149;">
   
           <noscript>I'm So Sorry, but Unlocked Academy requires you to have JavaScript enabled to run.
           </noscript>

           <div id="root">
           </div>
    
    
       </body>



    </html>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Only in one component it's not working? I tried your code and got it working. You may share your full Login component if it's only happening with `Login` Component

Comment: I'm sorry for not clarifying.  It does not work in ALL of the components I implemented it into (All components are using this same structure/format). I am testing via "inspection" of the page by right clicking it.  What method are you using to inspect if it is working or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works just fine for me when I tried. However if you right click and view page source you won't be able to see it. But if you open your developer tools and check the Elements, you will see all of it.

Here is an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cmjz7v

[image]

Comment: Interesting.  When I search "Unlocked Academy Login" on Google, it shows the image (inserted into the main question above).  I know I added a sitemap.xml file yesterday with Google.  But these meta tags have been inside the website for weeks. 

Any suggestions on how I can move forward to ensure these meta tags show up on Google Search/Web Crawling?

Comment: Not quite confident on SEO. Sorry. You may post another question on that.

Comment: One last question, so when I view the live website "elements" it shows the landing page title and not this Login Page title (circled in red in the 2nd image above).  Any idea why this would be the case?  

THANKS FOR YOUR TIME AND EXPERTISE!!!! :)

Comment: Keep an extra meta tag on landing page and see if it's getting added. Add a console.log in your landing page component where you have used Helmet. May be that page is re-rendering. Just a possibility.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help Sanish! :)

Comment: @SanishJoseph Hi, im stuck to something very similar to this, did you find any solutions regarding this issue? if yes, can you help me please. Thanks :)